# How to write a Safari plug-in now?

Tags: safari, safari-extension

Apple made [WebKit Plug-In Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/WebKit_PluginProgTopic/WebKit_PluginProgTopic.pdf) "retired" recently. But they didn't offer anything instead. Now it's not mentioned how to write a plug-in in the official docs.

So, plugins are dead (or at least are going to be unsupported), both NPAPI and Cocoa? Not yet: they're still mentioned in the [Extensions Development Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH1-SW3), see "Extensions Run in a Sandbox".

What does it all mean? How to write a "legal" Safari plug-in for OS X?

Answer (score 1):

If by "Cocoa" you mean the older Safari-specific WebKit plugin architecture, it's been unsupported for a while now.

NPAPI plugins are still supported by current versions of Safari, as long as you negotiate modern event and graphics models. However, given that Chrome no longer supports NPAPI, Mozilla refers to NPAPI plugins as "legacy technology", and you're seeing Apple retiring docs about them, you should think *very* carefully about whether you really want to develop a new plugin that uses a technology that the browser community is clearly moving away from.

The issue with your question is that it assumes that you should be writing a native plugin and asks how; instead you should explain what you want to accomplish, and ask how to accomplish that task in Safari.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to interact with another code outside Safari. Looks like I need to create a webserver on localhost and make GET/POST connections from the extension (with WebSockets it would be simpler, but only for Safari 7+).